# WindowState Maximized covers traybar when forms borderstyle is none

Tags: c#, maximize, borderless

I am using window form with borderstyle = none.
When I use the following code to maximize my window, it maximizes so that it covers the traybar.

```
    private void pb_max_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
        {
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            pb_max.Image = GomeeSoft.Properties.Resources.buttonmax;
        }
        else
        {
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            pb_max.Image = GomeeSoft.Properties.Resources.buttonreturn;
        }
    }
```

How do you maximize safely so that the frame is maximized only in the workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
this.MaximumSize = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size;
```

From MSDN:

`The working area is the desktop area of the display, 
excluding taskbars, docked windows, and docked tool bars.`